# NServiceBus Platform Installer - Failing To Install ServiceInsight - Chocolatey exit code 1638

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

Team,

I am installing the Platform Installer and selected NServiceBus, ServiceControl, ServicePulse, and ServiceInsight.  I am receiving the following error when it goes to install ServiceInsight (see error below)

I had the beta's version installed prior to this and uninstalled it and even rebooted my machine prior to kicking off the Platform Installer.

I found this url https://github.com/Particular/PlatformInstaller/issues/133 that indicates that there are similar issues with previous users who used the beta versions, but it does not identify a solution for us early adopters.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error executing powershell: [ERROR] Running C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\ServiceInsightInstall.exe with /quiet  /L*V "C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\msiexe.log" was not successful. Exit code was '1638'.
Error executing powershell: ServiceInsight did not finish successfully. Boo to the chocolatey gods!


[ERROR] [ERROR] Running C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\ServiceInsightInstall.exe with /quiet  /L*V "C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\msiexe.log" was not successful. Exit code was '1638'.

Error executing powershell: Package 'ServiceInsight.install v1.0.0' did not install successfully: [ERROR] Running C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\ServiceInsightInstall.exe with /quiet  /L*V "C:\Users\jmiller.MPSRX\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ServiceInsight\msiexe.log" was not successful. Exit code was '1638'.
```

Comment: Greg Bielleman  was kind enough to author a PS script to help cleanup betas of ServiceControl, ServicePulse and ServiceInsight. It will prompt for the removal of products based on the MSI product code so our various product name changes are catered for.
 
Script can be found here - https://gist.github.com/gbiellem/11394812 

I have tested this and it worked, as I was able to successfully install ServiceInsight using the Platform Installer after executing this script.  Note that it takes a while for the script to execute so please be patient.  Thank you Greg and NServiceBus for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple PS script to find and remove versions of the Service Insight, Service Control and ServicePulse products  based on the MSI product code.  This has successfully fixed up others in the same situation.

Script can be found here  - https://gist.github.com/gbiellem/11394812